# JavaScript Conform DialogBox is not Working,If I put Asp.Net Validation Control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

In a form there are two textboxes and a button whose value is submit. If any user clicks on the submit button after entering some values in the textboxes the value of the button changes to success i.e submit button becomes success button,

but my problem is that when any user clicks on submit button without entering any values in the textboxes it shows required field validation at the same time submit button becomes success button even form is not submitted.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">//code in default.aspx page
<div>
<div>   

    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="242px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
        ValidationGroup="s"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="242px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
        ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
        ValidationGroup="s"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <br />
    <br />


    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="MyButton" 
        OnClientClick="hello();" 

        onclick="btn1_Click" ValidationGroup="s" />

     </div>  

   </div>
   </form>


 //code in default.aspx.cs page

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


       protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

          btn1.Text = "Success";
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
OnClientClick="hello();"
```

what is it used for

or if using hope u have added the below function in script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function hello()
{
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both onclientclick and onclick handlers on same button. What are they performing? If you need the onclick, then try removing the onclientclick.

Comment: remove on client click and then try